# Set Treemapify subgroup colours in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, treemap

I want to set the specific colours for subgroups using Treemapify.

Here's a reproducible code sample

```
library(ggplot2)
library(treemapify)

name <- c("France", "Germany", "Chad", "Mali")
population <- c(100, 200, 300, 400)
parent <- c("Europe","Europe","Africa","Africa")
df <- data.frame(name, population, parent)
ggplot(df, aes(area = population, label = name, fill=parent, subgroup=parent)) +
geom_treemap() +
geom_treemap_text(colour = "white", place = "centre", grow = TRUE)
```

The colours are set by the fill, by default, they look like this:

[image]

I've tried changing `fill=c("green","green","yellow","yellow")` and `fill=c("#f00","#f00","#ff0","#ff0")`

But neither of those produce the colour I've specified.

I've tried manually specifying by adding `scale_fill_manual(values=c("#ff0000", "#ff0000", "#00ff00", "#00ff00"))`

But that doesn't render any colour.

How do I specify the colour for my sub-groups?

Comment: The colour is set against the `parent` field which only has two values. So `scale_fill_manual(values=c("#ff0000", "#00ff00"))` works to set the colours. Does this look like what you want, or did you want a unique colour per `name`? :)

Comment: Oh! I am a prat! That worked perfectly. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah I'm glad that solved the problem :)
Answer from the comments:

`scale_fill_manual(values=c("#ff0000", "#00ff00"))`